# How to use Spring in Jax-rs web service

Tags: spring, rest, java-8, jax-rs, tomcat8

I'm developing a REST service using JAX-RS and Java 8 and Tomcat 8.I already configuration using *{springconfig}.xml*. I want to know how to use **Spring** in **Jax-rs** web service for controller.I'm looking for answer.